# Having a hard time showing results after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asynchronous, sharepoint

**Browser:** IE 11

**PlatForm:** SharePoint 2016

I am trying to cache data into an array when page loads, so that the array can be used throughout the rest of my code for efficiency purposes.  I have 4 arrays and the data to populate the arrays will be coming form 4 different SharePoint lists.  I am using jQuery to make the calls to the lists and to retrieve the data.  I believe that the way I have done it is wrong because though the calls are successfully made the arrays are not populated by the time I use them.  Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
  getNavData();
  getSubNavData();
  getMegaMenuData();
  getCategoryMenuData();
})

function getNavData(){
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items";
var headers = {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url:endPointUrl,
    async:false,
    type:"GET",
    headers: headers,
    success: function success(data) {
        cacheNavData = data.d.results;
    }
});         
}

function getSubNavData(){
var endPointUrl =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items?$select=parentNav/URL, parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav";
var headers = {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url:endPointUrl,
    async:false,
    type:"GET",
    headers: headers,
    success: function success(data) {
        cacheSubNavData = data.d.results;
    }
});         
}

function getMegaMenuData(){
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items";
var headers = {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url:endPointUrl,
    async:false,
    type:"GET",
    headers: headers,
    success: function success(data) {
        cacheMegaMenuData = data.d.results;
    }
});         
}

 function getCategoryMenuData(){
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items";
var endPointUrl = "_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items";
var headers = {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url:endPointUrl,
    async:false,
    type:"GET",
    headers: headers,
    success: function success(data) {
        cacheCategoryMenuData = data.d.results;
    }
});         
 }

  console.log(cacheNavData);
  console.log(cacheSubNavData);
  console.log(cacheMegaMenuData);
  console.log(cacheCategoryMenuData);
```

Now, I know that the problem is Asynchronous and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.  I've looked at several problems and explanations on this site.  I've also looked at different articles and watched videos but I still don't fully get it.  In this situation, I know that when I'm looking to check the data in the console.log(), the Ajax call has not returned the data yet.  Through all of my readings, I have come to understand that. The part that I'm not getting is the fix or the how do I prevent that from happening.  I tried the following to fix this problem but it didn't work.  Maybe I did something wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cache1 = getData("Navigation", "cacheNavDataVar");
        var cache2 = getData("Sub Navigation", "cacheSubNavDataVar");
        var cache3 = getData("category menu", "cacheCategoryMenuDataVar");
        var cache4 = getData("Mega Menu Category", "cacheMegaMenuDataVar");

        $.when(cache1, cache2, cache3, cache4).done(function(results){
                            if(results){
                       createNavigation(cacheNavData)
                    }
        })

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: jquery ajax async false statement]
I hope above highlighted line is self explanatory. If you call multiple ajax async : true requests then browser opens new tcp port for every request and as soon it get response from any request, it starts calling ajax success function.